# Parsing XML with XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a XML with a structure similar to this:

```
<category>
   <subCategoryList>
      <category>

      </category>
      <category>
         <!--and so on -->
      </category>
   </subCategoryList>
</category>
```

I have a Category class that has a `subcategory` list (`List<Category>`). I'm trying to parse this XML file with XPath, but I can't get the child categories of a category.

How can I do this with XPath? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's the "and so on" ...that's important

Comment: Also the question is how big will your file be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This link](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml) has everything you need. In shorts:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
          IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("persons.xml");
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//person/*/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
     System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the XPath expression for this would be "`//category/subCategoryList/category`". If you just want the children of the root `category` node (assuming it is the document root node), try "`/category/subCategoryList/category`".

Comment: yes, but this returns me a list of all the nodes that matches that expression, so all the childs are included ... 
thanks

Comment: What do you mean all the children are included? I think you're leaving out some detail.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//category//subCategoryList/category",
inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Then you can parse the children of category as you wish.