# XML parsing /JAVA

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an XML, for example

```
<root>
 <config x="xxx" y="yyyy" z="zzz" />
 <properties>blah blah blah </properties>   
 <example>
   <name>...</name>
   <decr>...</descr>
 </example> 
 <example>
   <name>...</name>
   <decr>...</descr>
 </example> 
</root>
```

and I need to get nodes config, and properties and all values in it. 
Thank you

Comment: Step 1) try it yourself, step 2) if you have issues then come back and ask a specific question...

Comment: Also use the exact xml file because it has few errors in your xml file .

Answer (score 2):

Xpath can fetch you the data in the config tag. You need to create an expression first like this 
expression="//root/config/@x", to get value of x,y,z.
For properties, follow this thread :
[Parsing XML with XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340787/parsing-xml-with-xpath-in-java)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

DOM,DOM4J,SAX..

if the size of XML file is small,you can use DOM or DOM4J,but the size is big , you use the SAX

Answer (score 1):

If you directly want to query or fetch data XPath can help, but if you want the data as Java Objects so that you can use it further then use **JAXB**

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAX parser to read the xml manipulate its event based parsing and consumes more memory.
If your xml is big and requires lot of manipulations then go-for DOM/DOM4j either is good. DOM4L is very latest. DOM is widely used in industry.

Based on your requirement go for good parser.

Thanks,
Pavan