# how to i get the xpath value using 1 xpath from 2 different class?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<tr valign="middle">
   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a class="actionbtn" onclick="addFavourite();" href="#" data-hasqtip="1" oldtitle="Add   Record to Favourites" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-1">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a class="actionbtn" onclick="copyLink();" href="#" data-hasqtip="2" oldtitle="Copy Document Link URL" title="`enter code here`" aria-describedby="qtip-2">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a class="actionbtn" onclick="gotoEmailRecord();" href="#" data-hasqtip="3" oldtitle="Email Record" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-3">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a class="actionbtn" onclick="gotoMrkForDel();" href="#" data-hasqtip="4" oldtitle="Mark for Delete" title="">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a class="actionbtn" target="mainFrame" onclick="gotoViewCopy();" href="#" data-hasqtip="5" oldtitle="Open Document" title="">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a class="actionbtn" onclick="gotoGetCopy();" href="#" data-hasqtip="6" oldtitle="Get Copy" title="">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a id="idIconEditLn" class="actionbtn" onclick="gotoUpdate();" href="#" data-hasqtip="7" oldtitle="Edit" title="">
   </td>

   <td class="marginTd" width="25" align="right">
   <a id="idIconEditLn" class="actionbtn" onclick="lock();" href="#" data-hasqtip="8" oldtitle="Lock only" title="">
   </td>
</tr>
```

pardon me for my long xml file. i would like to get the integer value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) i have tried `.//*[@class='actionbtn'].getAttribute('data-hasqtip')` and `.//*[@class='idIconEditLn'].getAttribute('data-hasqtip')` but it isn't working. may i know is there any xpath can solve this problem can return me only the numbers? (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your XML is malformed. The  tags must be closed.

After you fix that, this will work `//@data-hasqtip`

Comment: thanks for sharing. i have test out the xpath you suggested it return me the whole length [data-hasqtip="1"] iszit possible to let it return only the number?

Comment: I imagine you're running into a library issue.  What are you using?  Often libraries will return something akin to a `Node` or `XNode` instance.  That node will have a `value` property.

Comment: oh, im doing some web automation. im using selenium and java to do it.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2818246/54996.  Assuming you're using that library, it does in fact have a `getNodeValue()` method.

Comment: yeap i saw that getNodeValue method.. what does it return?

Comment: You can directly use `//@data-hasqtip`, there is no difference to your query as attributes can only exist as direct children of element nodes.

Comment: @sssheng give it a whirl.  as i mentioned, each library will be different, but i suspect it will provide a string variant of your attribute value.