# parsing an XML with JAVA

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a few specific parts of an xml doc. I am looking at pulling the data out of the analysis section, I need the warnings, errors, passes and I need to go into each of the sections () and get the result and result level and the text for example in this "ERROR" I would need to get level of error and the text "ERROR".

```
<document>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <data>
    </data>
    <analysis warnings="5" errors="3" information="0" passed="false">
        <files>
        </files>
        <results>
            <form>
                <section number="0">
                    <result level="error">ERROR</result>
                    <result level="error">ERROR</result>
                    <result level="error">ERROR</result>
                    <result level="warning">Warning</result>
                    <result level="warning">Warning</result>
                </section>
                <section number="1">
                    <result level="warning">WARNING</result>
                </section>
                <section number="2">
                    <result level="warning">WARNING</result>
                    <result level="warning">WARNING</result>
                </section>
            </form>
        </results>
    </analysis>
</document>
```

I have the following code:

```
public void ProcessXMLFromPath(String path) throws Exception
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document =  builder.parse(path);
        NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
          Node node = nodeList.item(i);
          if (node instanceof Element) {
            System.out.println(node.getAttributes().toString());
            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
              Node cNode = childNodes.item(j);

              if (cNode instanceof Element) {
                  System.out.println(cNode.getNodeName().toString()); 
                  if(cNode.getNodeName().toString() == "analysis")
                  {
                      String content = cNode.getLastChild().getTextContent().trim();
                      System.out.println(content);
                      //I thought this would print the children under the analysis section to the screen but I was mistaken. It does however make it to this point.
                  }
              }
            }

          }

        }
    }
```

The only thing I'm getting to print to my console is:

```
configuration
data
analysis
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with the code:

1. `cNode.getNodeName().toString() == "analysis"`, do a String comparison with `.equals`
2. `analysis` is the direct descendant of `document` (per the xml piece we have here), so it has to be checked early on. Your code checks for it at `level 3` instead of `2`
3. You would need to drill further down the analysis to get the `results`, `form` and `text` nodes.

**EDIT:**
Based on comments, an efficient way to traverse without the multiple for loops woild be recursion, as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException, IOException {
    InputStream path = new FileInputStream("sample.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(path);
    traverse(document.getDocumentElement());

}

public static void traverse(Node node) {
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = list.item(i);
        traverse(currentNode);

    }

    if (node.getNodeName().equals("result")) {
        System.out.println("This -> " + node.getTextContent());
    }

}
```

This gives the result as:

```
This -> ERROR
This -> ERROR
This -> ERROR
This -> Warning
This -> Warning
This -> WARNING
This -> WARNING
This -> WARNING
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to parse individually line by line? Right now it prints the error and warning messages as 1 big block of text.

Comment: Is there anyway you could show me by updating your answer? I attempted to iterate but I keep making for for loops and trying to branch down and I know their has to be a better way.

Comment: @user1857654 updated the code above with the most efficient way (through recursion) and depicts your traversed nodes too

Comment: Boss, Thanks! Works great it looks way better than the for loops I was doing.

Comment: @user1857654 you're welcome, yes this is a way better approach.

Answer (score 0):

For each of these three (`configuration`, `data`, `analysis`), get their child nodes and drill down until you get to your errors (i.e. to your `result` tags). You will find these below `analysis` (but not directly below it). So you can just drill down from `analysis` downwards.

Comment: How would one go about doing that? Like how would I drill down into each section and subsection?

Comment: In the same way you got from `document` to `analysis`. Calling `getChildNodes()`.

Comment: Is there a better/cleaner way to do it? right now I'm seeing that I'll have several nested for loops and it looks really dirty.

Comment: Maybe you could look at XPath. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340787/parsing-xml-with-xpath-in-java

Comment: Another approach is to use another parser - e.g. SAX Parser or StAX Parser. Maybe that would be better for your case, if you're only interested in these `result` errors there. You're using a DOM Parser now.