# How to extract data from XML?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing

My XML will look like:

```
< Header>
    < Feature web="true" mob="false" app="true">some data< /feature>
< /Header>
```

I want java file with the data of web, mob, app in boolean and the somedata as string in java. How to extract data from xml? Please help

Comment: I would use XPath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340787/parsing-xml-with-xpath-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XML transformation** provided by java. This will return you something called **dom objects** which you can use for retrieving whatever data you have in the xml. In you case some attributes of feature tag and others.

Following this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html

Sample code to quickly try it ;-)

```
public class TransformXml {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlStr = "<Header><feature web=\"true\" mob=\"false\" app=\"true\">some data</feature></Header>";

        Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);

        String str = convertDocumentToString(doc);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            // below code to remove XML declaration
            // transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,
            // "yes");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
            String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
            return output;
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```