# XSL - iterate through elements and update based on the node index from another xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with multiple `Shape` elements each with a child `Material` element that contains a `Code` attribute.  I want to update the `Code` attribute for each `Material` element based on a value that is obtained from a separate XML file.  The problem I have is that the update source file also have multiple elements.

Here is the main XML file - main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Top-->
<Top>
  <Shapes>
    <!--Shape-->
    <Shape Code="Penisola" Description="Rectangle">
      <!--Material-->
      <Material Code="MAT01000257" ></Material>
    </Shape>
    <!--Shape-->
    <Shape Code="Penisola" Description="Rectangle">
      <!--Material-->
      <Material Code="MAT01000258" ></Material>
    </Shape>
  </Shapes>
  <Texts></Texts>
</Top>
```

...and my update source file - updatesource.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Job>
  <Job_Number>B90512</Job_Number>
  <Job_Address>2nd Floor/ 28-32 Albert Road   VIC 3205</Job_Address>
  <Benchtops>
    <Benchtop>
      <Material>Material 1</Material>
    </Benchtop>
    <Benchtop>
      <Material>Material 2</Material>
    </Benchtop>
  </Benchtops>
</Job>
```

The desired outcome is - output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Top-->
<Top>
  <Shapes>
    <!--Shape-->
    <Shape Code="Penisola" Description="Rectangle">
      <!--Material-->
      <Material Code="Material 1" ></Material>
    </Shape>
    <!--Shape-->
    <Shape Code="Penisola" Description="Rectangle">
      <!--Material-->
      <Material Code="Material 2" ></Material>
    </Shape>
  </Shapes>
  <Texts></Texts>
</Top>
```

I imagine I need to iterate through both the main XML and the update source XML, but I am unsure how to do this.  My attempts so far have only succeeded in updating both `Code` attributes with the value from the first `Material` element in the update source file.

Some extra information; both the main.xml file and the updatesource.xml file will have matching number of `Shape` and `Benchtop` elements respectively, however, the number of each will change with each job I process, so the solution will need to dynamically work through the number of elements present.

Comment: you can try using xpath. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340787/parsing-xml-with-xpath-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSL transformation that meets your requirement may be like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <!-- the update source file: -->
    <xsl:param name="usource" select="'updatesource.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template match="Material">
        <!-- Material's position: -->
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::Material)+1"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

            <!-- update Code-attribute according to pos-th Material in $usource --> 
            <xsl:attribute name="Code">
                <xsl:value-of select="(document($usource)//Material)[position()=$pos]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main points are to check at which position `Material` is located in the source. And then pick the corresponding one from `updatesoure.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="update-path" select="'updatesource.xml'" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Shape">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document($update-path)/Job/Benchtops/Benchtop[$i]/Material"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> however this will not update the Code attribute, it will replace the
>   existing Material element with the new one. I need to keep the
>   existing element and all other attributes within.

Then I would suggest you do:

```
<xsl:template match="Material/@Code">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(../../preceding-sibling::Shape) + 1" />
    <xsl:attribute name="Code">
        <xsl:value-of select="document($update-path)/Job/Benchtops/Benchtop[$i]/Material"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: I don't particularly like having to count preceding siblings instead of using the `position()` function, but the alternative in XSLT 1.0 is rather awkward, so unless you have a huge amount of records, you might as well live with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael, however this will not update the `Code` attribute, it will replace the existing `Material` element with the new one.  I need to keep the existing element and all other attributes within.

Comment: @paularmy42 I see. Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?