# Parsing Inner <p> tags

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing

I need to parse a xml content and need to find a inner tags inside the

```
<p><span>test</span></p> <p><span>test12</span></p>  <p>Some text<p><span>test</span></p></p>
```

In my above test the last p tag has inner p tag inside. I need to find inner p tags of p tag. i tried as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String  text= "<p><span>test</span></p> <p><span>test12</span></p>  <p>Some text<p><span>test</span></p></p>";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<p>.*?</p>");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    //System.out.println("matcher group:"+match);
    if (match.lastIndexOf("<p>") > 0) {
            //System.out.println("Substring:"+match.substring(match.indexOf("<p>") + "<p>".length(), match.indexOf("</p>")));
            text = text.replace(match, "<p>" +match.substring(match.indexOf("<p>") + "<p>".length(), match.indexOf("</p>")).replaceAll("<p>", ""));
        }
    }
 System.out.println("text:"+text);
}
```

Let me know if any easy way to do this.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions. Use a library specifically for XML parsing.

Comment: It's been pointed out several times (i.e: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/982542) that you cannot really parse `xml/html` with regular expressions. Rather use a proper parser (Oracle Official Guide here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm).

Comment: @AndyTurner html != xml. There is not guarantee that the OP's html is valid xml (even if it *can* be). The OP should use a html parser

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Indeed. OP said "I need to parse a xml content".

Comment: Maybe have a look at XPath (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340787/parsing-xml-with-xpath-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/).

As suggested by others, don't do this manually and instead use an existing library like JAXB.

An easy to understand JAXB hello world example can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/).